# In /proc/meminfo, which entries correspond to page in/out and swap in/out?

Tags: c, linux, proc

I'm writing a C++ program running on replit.com (ubuntu)

which is meant to parse the text in `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/stat` and collate some values related to cpu and memory usage.

One of the things I have to calculate is the **page in/out ratio** as well as **swap in/out ratio**.

I'm guessing "swap in" corresponds SwapCached and "swap out" corresponds to SwapFree, according to the descriptions of SwapCached and SwapFree here:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt.

Is this right? If not, where may I find this information?

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to find the running counters for swap in/out in `/proc/vmstat` as `pswpin` and `pswpout` (both are in pages since boot).

Similarly in the same place you'll find `pgpgin` and `pgpgout`, which are in and out since boot (These appear to be in KB).

Alternately, in `/proc/stat`, you may find these as the first and second numbers after `swap` and `page`, respectively (I'll note that part of the reason I say "may find" is that it is documented as architecture dependent, and none of these appear on my system).